# Updating two tables while avoiding foreign key conflict-ion

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

So basically, I have two tables:

> 1. ITEM_MASTER - srno(Primary Key), name(Unique Key)
> 2. SELL_RECORD - bill_no(Primary Key), name(Foreign key to ITEM_MASTER)

Now, if I want to update the name in ITEM_MASTER, the foreign key will conflict. 
what i did was:

```
//adding a new record with new name
INSERT INTO ITEM_MASTER VALUES('srno * -1', new_name)
//update sell record with new name 
UPDATE SELL_RECORD SET name = 'new_name' WHERE name = 'old_name'
//deleted the record with old name 
DELETE FROM ITEM_MASTER WHERE name = 'old_name' 
//restored the original srno 
UPDATE ITEM_MASTER SET srno = 'srno * -1' WHERE name = 'new_name'
```

This thing worked. What I wanted to ask is, is there any simple way around? 
For example, can I do:

```
UPDATE ITEM_MASTER, SELL_RECORD SET
ITEM_MASTER.name = 'new_name',
SELL_RECORD.name = 'new_name'
WHERE SELL_RECORD.name = 'old_name' AND ITEM_MASTER.name = 'old_name' AND ITEM_MASTER.name = SELL_RECORD.name
```

SOMETHING LIKE THAT? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can not update two table in a single update query in sql server. So you can not update ITEM_MASTER and SELL_RECORD in single update query as wish to do so.

Comment: So, the method I used is ultimately the only way to do it, right? @ManishMawatwal

Comment: Why don't you try cascade effect to update the child table along with parent table. e.g. you can use '... FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ITEM_MASTER(name) on update cascade'. It will save you writing seperate update and delete queries.

Comment: The way you do it is good. Can't think of anything simplier. Also, first query inserts new record and last query seems to update it, but it's not necessary, because, seems to me, liek it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn First query inserts a record with negative srno, the last query changes the srno to positive one after deleting the original record.

Comment: Why are you updating to the value you just inserted?  Why does the FK not use the primay key?

Comment: @Paparazzi Let me explain, suppose there is a record with srno 5, the first query creates a new record with srno "-5", and "new_name". This allows me to update the SELL_RECORD table. The second last, deletes the original record with srno "5". And Finally, the last one changes the srno from "-5" to "5".

Comment: Let me explain to you.  That is not what the last one is doing.

Comment: @paparazzo yes it is..

Comment: Buy a vowel.  `INSERT INTO ITEM_MASTER VALUES('srno * -1', new_name) UPDATE ITEM_MASTER SET srno = 'srno * -1' WHERE name = 'new_name'`

Comment: @paparazzo okay, multiplying any positive number with "-1" converts it into negative one and vise versa, I hope you get it now. :P

Comment: @PratikBhavsar I hope you get ' ' is a literal in TSQL. That is not TSQL to multiply.

Comment: @paparazzo dont know what you are trying to imply, but i know its working the way i said. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
Create table ITEM_MASTER 
(
smo varchar(20) Primary key,
name varchar(20) Unique
)

Create table SELL_RECORD
(
bill_no varchar(20) Primary key,
name varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ITEM_MASTER(name) on update cascade
)

Update ITEM_MASTER set name='new_name' where name='old_name'
```

Your child table SELL_RECORDS will get updated.

Comment: How can I do this in Visual Studio 2010? I am using vb.net in windows form application.

Comment: @Pratik Bhavsar, it needs to be verified in vb.net. If you want to update parent table for referenced row to child table then you can modify your foreign key relation with cascade in SQL SERVER, and try to update the ITEM_MASTER table from vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you would just do a proper foreign key where you reference `srno`(Primary Key) you could just update `name` at will (other than not violate the unique constraint).